# Embedding Tcl in a C program

Tags: visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2005, tcl, unresolved-external

I am trying to create a simple c++ console app that calls the nagelfar syntax checker on a script. I followed the directions here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/19919 , adding the `tclstub85.lib` to my input, adding the tcl lib directory to my additional libraries, and adding my header directory as well. Linking fails with:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _tclStubsPtr
```

This is my command line for linking:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\######\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Nagelfar\Release\Nagelfar.exe"
/NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Tcl\lib" /MANIFEST 
/MANIFESTFILE:"Release\Nagelfar.exe.intermediate.manifest" /DEBUG
/PDB:"c:\users\######\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\nagelfar\release\Nagelfar.pdb"
/OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT C:\Tcl\lib\tclstub85.lib
kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

This is the full source code, which I can compile and run fine in Linux using g++:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tcl.h>
#include <string.h>

Tcl_Interp * tcl_interp ;
char fileToCheck[] = "test.tcl";
char dbFile[] = "syntaxdb.tcl";

int main () {
    int code, argc;
    const char **argv;
    char command[1024];
    char *results = NULL; 
    tcl_interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_SetVar2(tcl_interp, "::Nagelfar", "embedded", "1", 0);  
    code = Tcl_EvalFile(tcl_interp, "nagelfar.tcl"); 
    Tcl_LinkVar(tcl_interp, "::Nagelfar(chkResult)", (char *)&results, TCL_LINK_STRING); 
    sprintf(command, "synCheck %s %s", fileToCheck, dbFile); 
    code = Tcl_Eval(tcl_interp, command);
    printf("Raw Result: \r\n %s\r\n", results); 
    code = Tcl_SplitList(tcl_interp, results, &argc, &argv); 
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d/%d: %s\r\n", i+1, argc, argv[i]); 
        }
    }
    Tcl_Free(results);
    return 0;
}
```

Solved my own problem: I had x64 ActiveTcl but was linking a 32 bit project. Using the x86 ActiveTcl distribution fixed my issues.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to your own question. It might help future visitors.

Comment: Sure thing, but I can't for a couple more hours =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem: I had x64 ActiveTcl but was linking a 32 bit project. Using the x86 ActiveTcl distribution fixed my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message tells us that you are expecting a stub table (Tcl's goes by the name `tclStubPtr` once all the macros are expanded), which in turn says that defining the preprocessor symbol `USE_TCL_STUBS`. That symbol is for use in the case where you are writing a library that is providing extra functionality to Tcl. However, in the case where you are writing a main application that calls functions in the Tcl library — such as “run this code” — you can't (easily) use the stubs mechanism as you'd be needing the stub table before Tcl is in a position to be able to provide it to you.

The fix is to *not* define `USE_TCL_STUBS` and to link against the main Tcl library (probably `C:\Tcl\lib\tcl85.dll` on your system) instead of `tclstub85.lib`. (I don't know enough about setting up Visual Studio to say what the details of that configuration are.)

---

You should also add this line to your code *before* the call to `Tcl_CreateInterp()`:

```c
Tcl_FindExecutable(NULL);
```

That call is used to allow the Tcl library core to initialize itself, doing little things like getting the memory manager and filesystem interface layer working.

Comment: Thank you, I did discover I was not supposed to use the stubs, but the root of my issue was I had downloaded a 64 bit Tcl library but had a 32 bit project.

Comment: @user Oooh yes, that wouldn't work. (Stubs is a great tech, but it doesn't try to solve all problems. That's a good thing really, as it is better to do one thing well than many things badly. :-))